# How to create a side cut/notch on a container in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am sure there is a clip widget somewhere which can do it, but I can't find it. Most of the documentation is about how to do it with bottom app bar. `CircularNotchedRectangle` only allows top notch. Here is what I want to achieve.

Currently I am using a custom clipper which is close, but not exactly right.

```dart
class RightConcaveClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    return Path()
      ..lineTo(size.width, 0)
      ..cubicTo(size.width - 20, 25, size.width - 20, 30, size.width - 30, 30)
      ..cubicTo(size.width - 62, 30, size.width - 62, 70, size.width - 30, 70)
      ..cubicTo(size.width - 20, 70, size.width, 90, size.width, 90)
      ..lineTo(size.width, size.height)
      ..lineTo(0, size.height);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper old) {
    return old != this;
  }
}
```

[image: The card with side cut]

Comment: Does your '+' orange button should be considered as a `FloatingActionButton`? Can you provide what you've already tried to implement ?

Comment: It's not a floating action button which is usually used once on a screen. I have created a custom clipper which is close, but not quite right.

Comment: Hi @PrabhakarBhat did you find a solution. I have to implement something similar

Answer (score 0):

You can use [flutter_custom_clippers](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_custom_clippers) 
It has very a number of custom clippers which includes the one you want. check the screenshot below.
[image]

Check  [link](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_custom_clippers)  for more screenshots of clippers supported by the package.

I hope it helps.